# Is 勺 really the phonetic component of 的?

Tags: etymology, phonology

The etymology of 的 is described [here](http://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/character-etymology.php?zi=%E7%9A%84). Is this resource correct is saying that 勺 is this character's phonetic component? I ask because it doesn't seem to hint at the correct pronunciation at all. 勺 is pronounced **sháo** while 的 is pronounced **de**. Thanks!

Comment: My guess is that 勺 must have had a different pronunciation or alternate readings in the past, thinking in centuries or millennia, of course.

Although this dictionary does not provide any of that, but it confirms that 勺 is the phonetic part.
http://lcprichi.hkbu.edu.hk/search/show_word.php?id=1794

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Modern Chinese has underwent many pronunciation changes since characters were first invented and phonetic components often reflect words as they were pronounced in [Old Chinese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Chinese) rather than modern Chinese.

The pronunciations of 的 and 勺 were much more similar in Old Chinese. [This link](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%9A%84) explains:

> 的 and 勺 had roughly similar pronunciations in Old Chinese; Baxter-Sagart reconstruct 的 as *t-lˤewk, compared with 勺 *m-t-qewk.

Note the that 的 character as originally used means "target" and is pronounced `dì` in Modern Mandarin. In modern times, it was borrowed to *also* represent the genitive particle `de` (this usage ultimately descends from 之; refer to this [previous question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/6007/166) for more information).

A few other modern Chinese languages still preserve the final `-k` in both of these words. For instance, Cantonese has the pronunciations `dik` (IPA: /tɪk/) and `zoek` (IPA: /t͡sœːk/) for 的 and 勺.

Comment: Btw, it's interesting that 的 is often pronounced 'di' in songs, when it would be pronounced as 'de' in normal speech. Is there any explanation for that?

Comment: @DrunkenMaster Your question is covered here: http://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/1551 In my opinion, the currently second highest voted answer there is the actual correct one.

Comment: For comparison, Karlgren’s reconstruction of 勺 and 的 were _*ɗi̭ok_ and _*tiok_, while 藤堂明保 Akiyasu Tōdō reconstructed them as _*dhiɔk_ and _*tɔ̈k_, respectively, for Classical Chinese.